# How can I use an SWT Calendar when I have all Joda DateTime objects?

Tags: java, datetime, widget, swt, jodatime

I am developing Java GUI on Windows (Eclipse and SWT).  I have a need for GUI user input of Dates (calendar widget) and then date/time (from data source) manipulation including dealing with different time zones.

I switched to Joda for better date/time manipulation as I believe this is better than standard SWT.  However, as I understand it Joda does not support its own calendar widget.

Can anyone advise me how to do this that would be compatible with SWT and Joda?

I see that direct referencing:

```
private org.joda.time.DateTime jodaDateTime;
private swt.DateTime swtDateTime;
```

is an option but wondered what others there are.

Comment: You should know that tool or library requests are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow. However, it's okay to present your problem and say "help me solve this problem"; if someone happens to present a tool, it's a little different. See: [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: Apologies for that and thanks durron 597 for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple enough conversion that you can just create utility methods to convert from and to the default SWT widget, e.g.

```
public class DateUtils {
  public static org.joda.time.DateTime makeJodaFromSWT(
                                org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DateTime widget) {
    return new DateTime(widget.getYear(),
                        widget.getMonth(),
                        widget.getDay(),
                        widget.getHours(),
                        widget.getMinutes(),
                        widget.getSeconds());
  }

  public static void updateSWTwithJoda(
                                org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DateTime widget,
                                org.joda.time.DateTime dateTime) {
    widget.setYear(dateTime.getYear());
    widget.setMonth(dateTime.getMonthOfYear());
    widget.setDay(dateTime.getDayOfMonth());
    widget.setHours(dateTime.getHourOfDay());
    widget.setMinutes(dateTime.getMinuteOfHour());
    widget.setSeconds(dateTime.getSecondOfMinute());
  }
}
```

I would need to know more about your project to come up with a "smarter" wrapping scheme than `public static` utility methods, but this should get you on the right track.

Comment: durron many thanks.  Haven't had time to get it to work but I get the idea.

Comment: @Nigele2 Don't forget you can accept this answer by clicking the hollow checkmark next to the vote buttons. See: [**What should I do when someone answers my question?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)